# Swift 3 HTTP request not going through

Tags: swift

I am trying to learn Swift and networking. I am making a simple HTTP Request to www.google.com and it does not seem to be executing. This is the code I have written

```
let url = URL(string: "www.google.com")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        print(response)
    }
```

This does not seem to execute. I have looked online and help is not there for Swift 3. How could I make a HTTP request in swift 3? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do know, I hope, that you cannot actually make an `http` request? You must use `https:`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `task.resume()`.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com:80/")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    print(response)
}
task.resume()
```

---

Oh and `https://` or `http://`

---

Here is my entire playground for this.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com:80/")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    print(response)
}
task.resume()
```

---

Updated to show how to use port.

Comment: Thanks how do I make it to a certain port?

Comment: @JonathanHsu Use a `:` after the host name. `"http://www.google.com:80/"` would use port `80` of the host `www.google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `task.resume()`, but you might have also forgotten to add app transport security domain exceptions, so if you haven't already, add this to your `Info.plist`.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>google.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```